# Guava's Optional.toJavaUtil() as method reference

Tags: java, java-8, guava, option-type

I'm stuck trying to pass `Optional.toJavaUtil()` as method reference to a `map` method (either `Optional.map()` and `Stream.map()`).

The simplified example of my code:

```
aLegacyService.getGuavaOptional()
    .toJavaUtil()
    .map(MyPojo::getAnotherGuavaOptional)
    .flatMap(Optional::toJavaUtil);    // <-- This doesn't compile
```

The compiler gives me a cryptic error:

```
Error:(177, 72) java: invalid method reference
  non-static method toJavaUtil() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I think the reason is that there are 2 methods: [instance method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#toJavaUtil--) and [static method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#toJavaUtil-com.google.common.base.Optional-), both with the same name. If I use lambda syntax, both variants work fine:

```
.flatMap(opt -> opt.toJavaUtil())            // This is OK
// and
.flatMap(opt -> Optional.toJavaUtil(opt));   // Also OK
```

**Q:** Is there a way to make this work with method reference? (e.g. by somehow specifying which of two methods I want to use?)

Comment: from the documentation --> _Unfortunately, the method reference Optional::toJavaUtil will not work, because it could refer to either the static or instance version of this method. Write out the lambda expression o -> Optional.toJavaUtil(o) instead._

Comment: @Aominè, oh, where were my eyes? :) Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Side-question: If both `aLegacyService` and `MyPojo` work with Guava Optional, wouldn't one combine the two directly and only convert to a Java Optional at the end?

Comment: @Thilo There is no `flatMap` equivalent in Guava's Optional. I was at first trying to use Guava's `transform` method, but then I have to write my own equivalent to flatMap because I get `Optional<Optional<SomeOtherPojo>>`. (Refactoring of that legacy service and its domain objects to use Java's Optional is not an option right now).

Comment: That's an odd piece of API design. The only difference I can see is the "or null if the argument is null." aspect of the static method. This seems like a far more marginal use case than wanting to use a method reference. Perhaps @LouisWasserman could provide some context.

Comment: No `flatMap` ("`transformAndConcat`") indeed... https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1450 :-(

Comment: @AndyTurner to me, it not only looks like a marginal use case, the “or null if the argument is null” behavior contradicts the entire idea of using optional instead of `null`…

Comment: @Holger indeed.

Comment: @AndyTurner @Holger The main idea, IIRC, of the static `Optional.toJavaUtil(Optional)` is that it can be used in automated replacements of Guava `Optional` with the JDK `Optional`; just stick that method call in as a conversion at places where a Guava `Optional` is passed in, and you get an exact equivalent, including getting `null` if the input is `null` (something which does, surprisingly, happen in some cases).

Comment: @ColinD ok, but why make it an overload? Calling it e.g. `toNullableJavaUtil` would have avoided the name clash, as well as pointing to the fact there is something fishy going on with the potentially-null optional.

Comment: One bit of insight: assuming your class contains both Guava `Optional` and JDK `Optional`, you can only import one. Assuming you import the newer JDK `Optional` then the method reference has to be `com.google.common.base.Optional::toJavaUtil` which is a lot less pleasant than `o -> o.toJavaUtil()`.